# THEOS: compiling error when calling method in other class (logos)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

i'm trying to implement this tweak using THEOS that calls another view on load
but i keep getting this error when i compile:
`Tweak.xm:13:57: error: class method '+onLeftMenu' not found (return type
      defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]
    [_logos_static_class_lookup$FoxTubeViewController() onLeftMenu];`

my code Tweak.xm file:
`%hook MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    %orig;
    [%c(LeftMenu) onCachedVideo];
}
%end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to use %c you should

```
#import "LeftMenu.h"
```

and if you don't want that 
you can call it from runtime
using

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

then call it like

```
[objc_getClass("LeftMenu") onCachedVideo];
```

GoodLuck