# Call different class method from my hooked class in theos

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

```
%hook FirstClass
 [self method2];
 %orig
%end
```

But `method2` is only available at a different class

How can i call it in this case ?

What i know so far:

- Use NotificationCenter to notify second class to load `method2`
- Somewhat related to using `%c` but not familiar with the full explanation

But this is way complicated, Is there any alternative way to do so

-- Update

I tried %c but i get this error

```
Tweak.xm:86:48: error: class method '+class' not found (return type
  defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]

                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Applied solution in here > [THEOS: compiling error when calling method in other class (logos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594145/theos-compiling-error-when-calling-method-in-other-class-logos)

But doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hi. Could you explain a little bit more? What classes are you going to use exactly? Write the code you are talking about in your update please.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method of another class it will have to be a class method (plus sign). You can then do `[%c(ClassName) method:];` If it is not a class method (minus sign) then you will have to have an instance of that class. Sometimes you can find a shared instance of a class and then use methods on that. `[[%c(ClassName) sharedInstance].propertyWhichIsOfAClassYouActuallyWant method:]`

Comment: What about when you don't have `sharedInstance` ? Using NSNotificationCenter or something like that ?

Comment: @AnthoPak - there is probably a `sharedInstance` somewhere in the lifecycle